# equation solving approach for the given equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$y^4-10y^3+5y^2+100y+100=0$
how to solve this equation ?

what will be the approach to solve this question.
Breaking $100$ into $84$ and $16$ and then solving could be one .

Comment: Put your math between dollarsigns (see edit).

Comment: You could always plug your values into the fourth formula :).

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Expand $(y^2-5y-10)^2$.